# I can not install LaTex

Tags: installing

I wanted to install Latex for windows 10. I have installed Tex Studio and tried to install the full version of MikTex. I use the website http://www.miktex.org/2.9/setup to install MikTex, but I see there are different options. The basic one which is 175.76 MB which says (To install a basic TeX/LaTeX system...) and the option of "...allows you download all packages... " which is 11.13 MB. I read that I need to install the second one but when I want to give a default path for reading and installing the software, it gives me an error (The directory is not a valid installation source source). I installed the first one successfully but when I want to run some LaTex files containing some packages, it asks to install that packages manually. Any idea that how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I need to say I need both MikTex and TexStudio. As I upgraded to windows 10, I encountered this problem.

Comment: Welcome! You can set up MikTeX to install packages on-the-fly rather than having to do it manually. Have you considered that option? Or you can use MikTeX's package manager to install packages.

Comment: So if the http://www.miktex.org/2.9/setup is not the right one for getting the full version? I have downloaded MikTex net installer which says download all the packages ....

Comment: How can I set up MikTeX to install packages on-the-fly rather than having to do it manually?

Comment: But do you really need to install packages for Mongolian, hieroglyphic and Phenician, for instance? For the missing packages, use `MiKTeX Package Manager` (a graphic interface).

Answer (score 2):

The basic installer does only install some packages and the basic tex system.  Therefore if you run TeX code using packages which are not installed the system asks to install them or does it if you have allowed that while the installation process.

In my opinion it is better to install the complete distribution.  That needs more time, okay, but you can use your TeX distribution without the need to be always online ...

Your message

> The directory is not a valid installation source source

simply means that you are not allowed to install there files.  Could it be that you have not the right for that (user account instead of admin account)?

Please add the complete path you used to your question.

Comment: Er... the OP tried your recommended option *first*. Presumably, they made a mistake. But just telling them to do it is probably not going to help find that mistake.

Comment: I am installing as an admin.

Comment: Sometimes installing as admin can cause permissions problems.  Check your install instructions carefully. Try updating, http://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/259123/trouble-installing-and-using-texmaker-with-windows-10